# RegExp code to find equally-spaced characters in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'll be implementing the RegExp in JavaScript.

I think the best way to explain this is with an example. If the search string is

```
'abc'
```

and the haystack is

```
'auaisdgbbhbcsccddciubbffs'
```

the pattern needs to hit:

```
'[a]uaisdg[b]bhbcsc[c]ddciubbffs' and
'au[a]isdgb[b]hbcsc[c]ddciubbffs'
```

and return the positions of these characters...

Can Regex even be made to do such a thing?

Comment: which language and what have you tried?

Comment: I can't get the rules you want the regex to implement with your only example. Could you provide a less complex one? E.g., what should "azbzcz", "abc", "aabbcc" and "aazbzcc" match?

Comment: I don't think regex per se can do this, unless you know the maximum space between characters (and then you can make a lengthy, exhaustive, ugly regex for it). A better way might be to parse the string, count the characters between the first and second matching letters, then search for the third.

Comment: Note that the documentation for the [regex] tag includes this line: "Please also include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using." No two regexes are implemented in exactly the same way, so this question is impossible to answer in its current form.

Comment: apologies; currently using JavaScript; updated to reflect this

Comment: your ask about evenly spaced characters..so your pattern should have been `[a]uaisdg[b][b]hbcs[c][c]dd[c]iu[b][b]ffs`

Comment: I changed "evenly" to "equally" to avoid confusion. Please use the 'rollback' feature if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that we don't know the programming language you are using, it's impossible to provide a definitive answer at this point.

That said, I am not aware of any regex construct which would allow this sort of match.

If I understand correctly, you want to find an 'a' which, for example, is followed by a 'b' six characters later. Then, because 'b' occured six characters after 'a', you want to find a 'c' six characters after 'b'. Essentially, you want [backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), but you want to match only the length of the backreference and not the actual text. I don't think this is possible with regular expressions.

It's possible that some regex implementation out there has an uncommon construct which allows this, so knowing your platform would help.

**UPDATE**

Javascript has one of the [least powerful](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) regex implementations out there. I don't think you are going to be able to do this with pure regexp. You'll need to write some additional code (and I'd honestly recommend a "code only" approach for your simple example).

Comment: op wants evenly spaced a,b,c characters..he never said to match a character exactly n times after the last match..i guess op should clarify his question

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ - You need to read "between the lines". The OP's examples are "evenly spaced" in the sense that the matched characters  are exactly the same distance apart. It would have been more accurate for the OP to say "equally spaced", but the intent was clear (to me).

Comment: Thanks Cyborgx37! This answers what I suspected: RegExp isn't the best solution.

Comment: @Romi - Don't forget to accept an answer. It will help you to get answers in the future.

Comment: @Romi - You may also want to consider user1775603's suggestion. You could build a regex string in a for loop, escalating from 0 ('abc') to some arbitrary max (20, for example). It might be easier than parsing it yourself.

Comment: Thanks again Cyborg37, it's pretty clear that I'm new around here :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, a regular expression like this might work:

```
"(a).{6}(b).{6}(c).{6}.*"
```

You would want to join groups 1, 2, and 3.

Since you didn't specify a language, consider the following example in python that uses the strings you give above:

```
>>> q = re.compile(r"(a).{6}(b).{6}(c)")
>>> s1 = 'auaisdgbbhbcsccddciubbffs'
>>> s2 = 'auaisdgbbhbcsccddciubbffs'
>>> res1 = q.findall(s1)
>>> res2 = q.findall(s2)
>>> print res1, res2
[('a', 'b', 'c')] [('a', 'b', 'c')]
>>> for r in res1:
    print ''.join(r)

abc
>>> for r2 in res2:
    print ''.join(r)

abc
```

Comment: +1 `6` is an arbitrary number, but it could be useful to the OP if the regex is constructed in a for loop and applied multiple times with different widths. Not very efficient, but it could get the work done.

Answer (score 0):

In perl, you can return the position of matches using $+[1], etc.

e.g.

```
$x=qqqafkewibslspcfjfjfj;
$x=~/(a).*(b).*(c)/;
print 'a was at: ' . $+[1] . ' b was at: ' . $+[2] . ' c was at:' .  $+[3];"
```

give me:

```
a was at: 4 b was at: 10 c was at:15
```

Comment: OP has since updated his/her question to indicate javascript as the language.